# C3 bargraph going upper-side if we give y axis max value and the data array are same

Tags: d3.js, graph, c3.js

I am facing an issue, When ever I execute the below mentioned code, the graph plots on top area of the graph

```
chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 2, 2]],

    type:'bar'    
},
axis: {
    y: {
      tick: {
        values: [0,1,2]
      },
      max: 2

    },
}});
```

[image]

Any body please help me to place the graph at x-axis

Answer (score 0):

When you specify **max**, you should also specify **min**:

```
// variant A
chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 2, 2]],

    type:'bar'    
},
axis: {
    y: {
      tick: {
        values: [0,1,2]
      },
      min: 0, // here
      max: 2
    }
}});
```

or **skip both** of them and let chart scale automatically:

```
// variant B
chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 2, 2]],

    type:'bar'
},
axis: {
    y: {
      tick: {
        values: [0,1,2]
      }
    }
}});
```